# Solution to Nbody problem won't resolve, even for N=1

Tags: python, differential-equations

I'm trying to recreate the NBody problem, with python code. I made a class that holds particles in a single list, first the x and y position of a particle, then the x and y velocities of that particle, and then the next particle. When I however, try to run this code and resolve it for a particle of mass 1, and initial x velocity 1, I get a diagonal line. When I attempt to run this code with 2 particles, I get an error code (If I've left out some important information, please say so. This is my first post here).

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate
class NBody():
    
    G = 1
    t = []
    rv= []
    m = []
    def __init__(self, G, t):
        
        self.G = G
        self.t = t
        
    def addMass(self, mass, initPos, initVel):
        
        self.m = mass
        for i in initPos:
            self.rv.append(i)
        for i in initVel:
            self.rv.append(i)
        
    def FNBody(self, t, rv):
        
        rx = rv[0::4].copy()
        ry = rv[1::4].copy()  
        vx = rv[2::4].copy()  
        vy = rv[3::4].copy()  
        
        n = len(rx)
            
        F = np.zeros(n*4, dtype=np.float)    
        for i in range(n):
            addx = 0
            addy = 0
            for j in range(n):
                if i != j:
                    addx+=self.G*self.m[i]*self.m[j]*(rx[j]-rx[i])/((rx[i]-rx[j])**2+(ry[i]-ry[j])**2)**1.5
                    addy+=self.G*self.m[i]*self.m[j]*(ry[j]-ry[i])/((rx[i]-rx[j])**2+(ry[i]-ry[j])**2)**1.5
            F[4*i]=vx[i]
            F[4*i+1]=vy[i]
            F[4*i+2]=addx
            F[4*i+3]=addy
        
        return F
    
    def solveODE(self):
          
        return integrate.solve_ivp(self.FNBody, (self.t[0],self.t[len(self.t)-1]),self.rv,t_eval=self.t)
```

This yields a diagonal line, even though we'd expect a straight line. If I run a similar code, without initial velocities but with a second particle, I get a TypeError message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-9680340d6ca4> in <module>
      3 myN2Body.addMass(1,[0,0],[0,0])
      4 myN2Body.addMass(1,[1,1],[0,0])
----> 5 sol = myN2Body.solveODE()
      6 
      7 plt.figure(1)

<ipython-input-54-0e1c24c59824> in solveODE(self)
     63 
     64 
---> 65         return integrate.solve_ivp(self.FNBody, (self.t[0],self.t[len(self.t)-1]),self.rv,t_eval=self.t)
     66 

/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/ivp.py in solve_ivp(fun, t_span, y0, method, t_eval, dense_output, events, vectorized, args, **options)
    541         method = METHODS[method]
    542 
--> 543     solver = method(fun, t0, y0, tf, vectorized=vectorized, **options)
    544 
    545     if t_eval is None:

/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/rk.py in __init__(self, fun, t0, y0, t_bound, max_step, rtol, atol, vectorized, first_step, **extraneous)
     93         self.max_step = validate_max_step(max_step)
     94         self.rtol, self.atol = validate_tol(rtol, atol, self.n)
---> 95         self.f = self.fun(self.t, self.y)
     96         if first_step is None:
     97             self.h_abs = select_initial_step(

/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/base.py in fun(t, y)
    137         def fun(t, y):
    138             self.nfev += 1
--> 139             return self.fun_single(t, y)
    140 
    141         self.fun = fun

/software/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_ivp/base.py in fun_wrapped(t, y)
     19 
     20     def fun_wrapped(t, y):
---> 21         return np.asarray(fun(t, y), dtype=dtype)
     22 
     23     return fun_wrapped, y0

<ipython-input-54-0e1c24c59824> in FNBody(self, t, rv)
     49             for j in range(n):
     50                 if i != j:
---> 51                     addx+=self.G*self.m[i]*self.m[j]*(rx[j]-rx[i])/((rx[i]-rx[j])**2+(ry[i]-ry[j])**2)**1.5
     52                     addy+=self.G*self.m[i]*self.m[j]*(ry[j]-ry[i])/((rx[i]-rx[j])**2+(ry[i]-ry[j])**2)**1.5
     53             F[4*i]=vx[i]

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Edit: It was pointed out that my mass definition was botched, it's fixed now. I've also added a clearmass function to the class. Here's what things look like right now:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate
class NBody():
    
    G = 1
    t = []
    rv= []
    m = []
    def __init__(self, G, t):
        
        self.G = G
        self.t = t
    def clearmass(self):
        self.m = []
        self.rv = []
    def addMass(self, mass, initPos, initVel):
       
        self.m.append(mass)
        for i in initPos:
            self.rv.append(i)
        for i in initVel:
            self.rv.append(i)
        
    def FNBody(self, t, rv):
        
        rx = rv[0::4].copy()
        ry = rv[1::4].copy()
        vx = rv[2::4].copy()
        vy = rv[3::4].copy()  
        
        n = len(rx)
    
        F = np.zeros(n*4, dtype=np.float)    
        for i in range(n):
            addx = 0
            addy = 0
            for j in range(n):
                if i != j:
                    addx+=self.G*self.m[j]*(rx[j]-rx[i])/((rx[i]-rx[j])**2+(ry[i]-ry[j])**2)**1.5
                    addy+=self.G*self.m[j]*(ry[j]-ry[i])/((rx[i]-rx[j])**2+(ry[i]-ry[j])**2)**1.5
            F[4*i]=vx[i]
            F[4*i+1]=vy[i]
            F[4*i+2]=addx
            F[4*i+3]=addy
        
        return F
    
    def solveODE(self):
     
        return integrate.solve_ivp(self.FNBody, (self.t[0],self.t[len(self.t)-1]),self.rv,t_eval=self.t)
```

Then I run this code in the 1N variation using

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
time = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)

myN1Body = NBody(G=1, t=time)
myN1Body.clearmass()

myN1Body.addMass(1,[0,0],[1,0])
myN1Body.rv
sol = myN1Body.solveODE()

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(sol.t, sol.y[0, :])
plt.show()
```

Which creates the mentioned diagonal line. In the 2N variation I use

```
time = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
myN2Body = NBody(G=1, t=time)
myN2Body.clearmass()
myN2Body.addMass(1,[0,0],[0,0])
myN2Body.addMass(1,[1,1],[0,0])
sol = myN2Body.solveODE()

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(sol.t, sol.y[0, :])
plt.show()
```

Which creates the exponential. I'd expect the 1N variation to create a line, in the direction of the initial velocity, and the 2N variation to create 2 diagonal lines.

Comment: You sum up the forces, but what you need in the derivatives vector is the associated acceleration. So divide by mass i or do not multiply with it in the first place. // As you ever only access the rv argument to the ODE function by reading, you do not need to copy the subarrays.

Comment: Like the error message says, it's trying to index into an integer so something that should be a list is instead an integer. In this case self.m is an integer instead of a list. This is because in your definition of addMass you overwrite the mass rather than appending to it.

Also, note that your variables are now global to the class rather than the instance. This could cause problems if you run things repeatedly.

Comment: I fixed the error where I overwrite the mass, that was a dumb oversight on my part. It still doesn't display the expected graph, however. The 2 body version now creates an exponential looking graph, and the 1 body version is still a diagonal

Comment: I've tried running your code and for me it seems to work more or less correctly. Post how you are calling it.

Comment: I don't know how to add a codeblock in these comments, So I updated the original post.

Comment: You are plotting x coordinate as function of time so it makes perfect sense that it grows linearly in the 1 body case and at an accelerating rate in the 2 body case. If you want to plot the trajectory you need to plot both x and y: plt.plot(sol.y[0, :], sol.y[1, :]).